# fail to using jersey in android studio

Tags: java, android, web-services, jersey

I'm tring to use jersey with an app that I build. When I use ClientBuilder and WebTarget I always got an error that I missing some imports. does someone know what all(or some) of the jars I need so I can make a get and post request using jersey

Comment: Use volley instead !

Comment: thanks for your answer :) , I'm new in web services so I will read about volley and try it

Comment: Volley can do http request, keep using jersy

Comment: Use Volley instead client builder because it does http request